# The mine does not explode when driven over. However the mines do explode when shot or otherwise destroyed

Tags: sqf

I'm trying to code a mine in VBS4. I think I need to add some sort of a detection for it to detect the vehicles, but am not sure how. I thought my code would work as it is, but it does not.

Config.cpp

```cpp
class vbs2_ammo_E_mineAT_TM62M;
    class pohjamiina_ammo_dest : vbs2_ammo_E_mineAT_TM62M {
        scope = public;
        indirectHit = 3;
        indirectHitRange = 4;
        craterSize = 0.15;
        model = __CurrentDir__\pohjamiina;
    };
```

config.cpp

```cpp
class EventHandlers
        {
            Killed = _this execVM 'vbs2\customer\weapons\pohjamiina\data\scripts\destroyed.sqf'
        };
```

destroyed.sgf

```
_mine = _this select 0;
_position = position _mine;
deleteVehicle _mine;
_bomb = createMine ["pohjamiina_ammo_dest", _position, [], 0];
_bomb setDamage 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

For mines, you will need a class in `CfgVehicles` that will contain your mine. You will also need an ammo class in `CfgAmmo` which you will then add to your CfgVehicles class in the form of `ammo = "myAmmoClass"`. Inside your `CfgAmmo` class is a value called `mineTrigger`. You can reference the available triggers in `CfgMineTriggers` but for vehicles, you could use `"TankTriggerMagnetic"`.